# Where can I learn to refactor code?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Where can I learn to refactor code?

Comment: Do you have a suite of unit tests in place?

Comment: unit tests are great but they have nothing to do with refactoring

Comment: @msarchet: why not? You can assess application performance with unit tests.

Comment: In the brownfields of the real world! :)

Comment: @BoltClock yes you can but refactoring doesn't asses code performance

Comment: Unit tests do have something to do with refactoring. Refactoring means changing code. Doing that in a legacy app, one without Unit tests, is just... crazy. How would you know if you broke something.

Comment: *Where can I learn to refactor code?* - [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a great place to learn.

Answer (score 9):

Books.
See [http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279262199&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

Comment: I'm currently reading this book and it starts quite simple but usefull. It's a good read and the most complete work about refactoring AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

You can learn on the job by using a refactoring tool such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and asking yourself, why is it suggesting this change? It will show you places where you can make your code simpler as well as which code is not being used any where. One you have taken this first step, it is easier to see what your code is doing and then you can perform your manual refactoring as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Fowler's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201485672) is a good place to begin, but before doing any refactoring you should make sure you have automated tests for your code. Refactoring without tests is risky at best.

Visual Studio supports the most common refactoring operations, but you may also want to take a look at Resharper, which adds additional tools.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring - C# Tutorials | Dream.In.Code

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/77242-refactoring/

C# 2.0 Code Refactoring

http://www.premier-club.com/codemag/Article/20143

Answer (score 1):

See Martin Fowler's material: http://www.refactoring.com/

His articles are very good, recommended to anybody who wishes to learn beyond the basics
of just writing code.

Robert Martin's blogs (Uncle Bob) are also excellent.

In practise, choose any IDE which supports common refactoring like Eclipse or IntelliJ (latter is my favorite). But it's just a tool -- it helps to learn what are the reasons why a piece of code should be refactored and how.

Comment: Do you mean this uncle bob? 
https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/

Comment: Yes, I mean that Bob :)

Answer (score 0):

Head over to [LosTechies](http://www.lostechies.com/) and have a look at the ebook 31 days of refactoring, its an easy way to start.

Then as others here have said, read Fowler's book when you have the time.